# Why the for loop is not using the 'i' specified in the function

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 25 weeks of observations per animal and 20 animals in total. I am trying to write a function that calculates a linear equation between 2 points each time and do that for the 25 weeks and the 20 animals.

I want to use a general form of the equation so I can calculate values al any point. In the function, Week=t, Weight=d.

I can't figure out how to make this work. I don't think the loop is working using each row of the data frame as the index for the function. My data frame named growth looks something like this:

```
Week   Weight Animal
1        50      1
2        60      1
n=25
1        80      2
2        90      2
                 .
                 .
                 20

for (i in growth$Week){
    eq<- function(t){
      d = growth$BW.Kg
      t = growth$Week
      (d[i+1]-d[i])/(t[i+1]-t[i])*(t-t[i])+d[i]
      return(eq)
    }
}

eq(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I think there are a few points of confusion here. The first is writing a function inside a for loop. What is happening is that you are re-writing the function over and over, and also your function doesn't save the values of your equation anywhere. Secondly, you are passing t as your argument but the expecting t to follow the for loop with the i value. Finally, you say that you want this to be done for each animal, but the animal value is not shown in your code.

So it's a little bit hard to see what you are trying to achieve here.

Based on your information above, I've rewritten your function into something that will provide a result for your equation.

```
library(tidyverse)
growth <- tibble(week = 1:5,
             animal = 1,
             weight = c(50,52,55,54,57))

eq <- function(d,t,i){

  z <- (d[i+1]-d[i])/(t[i+1]-t[i])*(t-t[i])+d[i]
  return(z)
}

test_result <- eq(growth$weight,growth$week,3)
```

Results:

```
[1] 57 56 55 54 53
```

Is that the kind of result you were expecting? Or did you want just a single result per week per animal? Could you provide a working example of a formula that would produce a single desired result (i.e. a result for animal 1 on week 1)?

Comment: I want somehow to index each row in the data frame into the function.   The first function for the first animal for example=(weight[2]-weight[1])/(week[2]-week[1])*(week-week[1]+weight[1], so instead of writing each of the next points (week3 and week2...week24 and week25), I was writing the function inside of the loop.  I have to index weight and week for the first observation and go along the whole data frame using the general form of the function which is d[i+1]-d[i])/(t[i+1]-t[i])*(t-t[i])+d[i] (where d=weight, t=week and the t without the i represent week at any given point).

Comment: I think you should step back and clarify what kind of end result you want, and then work backwards to how to achieve it. Do you want (A) 1 column with animal ID and then 25 columns with weekly change values? Or (B) do you want a column with animal ID and then a column with week number and a column with a weight value? Option A would mean one row per animal, while B would mean 25 rows per animal.

Comment: It would be option B then.

Comment: You don't need a for loop for this, you can do it in `dplyr` using the `mutate()` function. I still don't really understand what you want to achieve with your formula, it doesn't really make sense to me. `(weight[2]-weight[1])/(week[2]-week[1])*(week-week[1]+weight[1]` - this is the formula you gave, but what values are you expecting for `week` - is it supposed to be the integer for the week number? i.e. if the weight for week 2 is 80 and for week 1 is 75, is this the formula you want: `(80 - 75) / (2 - 1) * (2 - 1 + 75)`

Comment: The formula is a linear equation between 2 points and week is just the time I want to "predict" base on that line. I know I can fit a regression line but for now, this what I need to do.  For example, weights between week 1 and 2, can be used them to estimate the weight at week 3, weights at week 4 and 5 can be used to estimate the weight at week 6 and so on. At the end what I want to accomplish is to estimate how many previous data points I need to estimate weight a certain week.  I.e to estimate the weight at week 20 only need the previous 4 data points or 5.  Sorry I've not been very clear.

Comment: Was the formula I gave in my previous comment correct? Is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: The formula will be how you wrote it fisrt in the code. z <- (d[i+1]-d[i]) / (t[i+1]-t[i])*(t-t[i])+d[i])

Comment: Yes, it is correct, (weight[2]-weight[1])/(week[2]-week[1])*(week-week[1]+weight[1].  Also, are you suggesting to use the mutate function so it will use all the previous values?

Comment: I think we must have a language communication failure here. Using real numbers can you show me what would be an ideal formula? Because it is still not at all clear what the value of the week by itself (no i) should be here: `(*week*-week[1]+weight[1].` If the week number is 1 and the weight value for week 1 is 50, should this be `1-1+50`?

Comment: The week can be any value, I think the confusion is because I am using the same name in the formula, but it can be any number. Week[i] and weight[i] on the other hand, depend on the observation in the data frame so i is from 1 to 25 for each of the 20 animals. If the week number is 1 and the weight value for week 1 is 50 *week*1+50, where *week* can be any given number.  Is that make sense?